# Standard SQL is "IS NOT NULL" redundant when you have matching condition?

Tags: sql, null

If i say

```
   where C1 is not null   -- redundant given next line?
   and C1 > 5

   (or "C1 like 'MOM'", or "C1 <> 5" or "C1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

is the `where C1 is not null` redundant?  Are there any "trick" cases where it's not clear?

I use MS and IBM sqls but figure the answer will apply to SQL generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server, if a value is `NULL`, any comparison with `=`, `>`, `<`, `!=`, `<>`, etc. will give unknown, which is considered as false. So if `C1` is `LIKE` something or `<>` something or `IN` something, then it's definitely not `NULL`.

You usually check for conditions like `C1 IS NULL OR C1 = 0`. The use of `IS NOT NULL` is redundant if you perform another evaluation of that value.

Edit: Thanks @Martin Smith for the correction.

Comment: It is `unknown` rather than `false` but the rest is correct (if it was false you could make it true by adding a `not` but `not unknown` is also unknown)